# How to get the objects from an oracle table of row objects

Tags: sql, oracle, object, types

When dealing with an oracle table containing row objects I would expect that each row is an object and I can invoke functions on it or pass it to functions in any context.

As an example if I declare the following:

```
create type scd_type as object
(
  valid_from date,
  valid_to date,
  member function get_new_valid_to return date
);

create type scd_type_table as table of scd_type;

create table scd_table of scd_type;

create procedure scd_proc (in_table in scd_type_table)
as
begin
  ... do stuff ...
end;
/
```

And now I try to call my proc with the table

```
begin
  scd_proc (scd_table);
end;
/
```

I get an error. Even reading the rows into a nested table is not straight forward. I would expect it to work like this:

```
declare
  temp_table scd_type_table;
begin
  select * bulk collect into temp_table from scd_table;

  ... do stuff ...
end;
/
```

but instead I have to call the constructor for every line.

And last I cannot invoke functions in a merge statement even though it works in an update statement. Example:

```
update scd_table st
set st.valid_to = st.get_new_valid_to(); <--- Works.

merge into scd_table st
using (select sysdate as dateCol from dual) M
on (st.valid_from = M.dateCol)
when matched then update set st.valid_to = st.get_new_valid_to(); <--- Does not work.
```

So I guess there are three sub-questions here:

1) What is the easiest way to pass a table of row objects into a procedure expecting a nested table of the same type?

2) What is the easiest way to convert a table of row objects into a nested table of the same type?

3) Why can't I invoke functions on an object as part of a merge statement (but in an update statement)?

which all come down to the question of "How to extract objects from a table of row objects?".

Comment: "I get an error".  What error?  Also please post the relevant code.

Comment: @APC: The error I get is  
ORA-06550: line 2, column 12:  
PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'SCD_TABLE' not  
allowed in this context  
But that is mainly irrelevant since the error message is clear. The question is: Why does it appear and how to achieve the same thing in the simplest manner possible.

Comment: @APC: I don't understand what you mean by: "Please post the relevant code." I did post all the code relevant I think. If you feel like some specific piece of code is missing please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help but think you need to re-read the [documentation on PL/SQL types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjplsql.htm).

You were close with the bulk collect code. Minor change given below:

```
declare
  plsql_table scd_type_table;
begin
  select VALUE(t) bulk collect into plsql_table from scd_table t;
  -- do stuff
end;
/
```

I will admit, I have no idea why the `merge` fails but the `update` works.

Comment: Well, my understanding was that if I have a "table of obj" each row in the table is an object already. So why do I need to call the constructor again to instantiate it. Isn't there a way to get the row object directly?

Comment: I don't use objects so much, so forgive my misunderstanding. Could you use the `VALUE` or `REF` functions instead?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still leaves me wondering about the merge vs update issue but my main problem is solved. Thx.